# Creating a foreign key in a factTable to subsequently create a dimTable to where the foreign key becomes the primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following factTable:

[image: As-Is Table]

I want to add a `RegionID` to the `factTable` above so that I can use the `RegionID` to subsequently reference it to a `dimRegion` using the `RegionID`. This is the desired table:

[image: the desired table]

Can anyone help me with a SQL query to use so that I can create a numerical reference to `Region` column and create `RegionID`? I would like to avoid creating a sub-table for Region and subsequently join the sub-table to the fact table.

I tried creating the sub-table with only Region and using `Row_Number()` to create a unique key and subsequently joining this sub-table but there are lots of columns for me to include in SELECT statement.

If there's any SQL function for me to achieve this without creating any sub-table, that would be great.

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you replace pictures with text diagrams, post the DDL for your tables and post the sample SQL you tried. In the meantime, when building a dimension in sql server, you almost always use an `identity` to autogenerate the surrogate key. First step: insert a record into the dimension. Thie record needs to _include_ the source systems key. Now when you need to attach this dimension record to the fact, you need to take the source system key in the fact (the source transaction record), look it up in the dimension, get the surrogate key and apply it back to the fact

Answer (score 0):

A little crude but something like this...

```
-- start by replicating sample data
CREATE TABLE MyFactTable (SalesID INT, Region varchar(20))
INSERT INTO MyFactTable values 
    (1, 'XYZABC'),
    (2, 'XYZABC'),
    (3, 'ABCABC'),
    (4, 'ABCABC'),
    (5, 'ABCABC'),
    (6, 'DEFABC'),
    (7, 'DEFABC')
GO

    CREATE TABLE DimRegion(RegionID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Region varchar(20));
    INSERT INTO DimRegion (Region)
        SELECT DISTINCT Region FROM MyFactTable;

    ALTER TABLE MyFactTable ADD RegionID INT;
    
    UPDATE f
        SET RegionID = d.RegionID 
        FROM MyFactTable f 
        JOIN DimRegion d on f.Region = d.Region;

   ALTER TABLE MyFactTable ALTER COLUMN RegionID INT NOT NULL;
   ALTER TABLE MyFactTable DROP COLUMN Region;

   SELECT * FROM MyFactTable;
   SELECT * FROM DimRegion;
```

**Result:**

[image]